# Why $('#id').on('click', function (event) { ... }); doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have developed a movie seeker. Every found movie is compound by the movie title and one movie's poster. Found movies are display inside a list (`<ul>`). Every movie title is an anchor with same `id='movie'`.

```
<li>
    <p>
       <a id="movie" href="#"> title </a>
    </p>
    <img src="thumbnailSrc">
</li>
```

When a title is clicked, I want to run this:

```
$('#movie').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Hello World!');
});
```

But it doesn't work. Anyoine knows why? I suppose it has to be the id but I don't know how to solve it. I've tried to debbug it with Chrome tool but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: *Every movie title is an anchor with same id='movie'.* Wrong choice, `id` attributes must be unique within an HTML document. Use a class instead.

Comment: wrap it in $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: I've wrapped it but still doesn't work. I've changed also id to class.

Comment: I've just also tried to do the search with `$('li')`, `$('p')` and `$('a')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change your id="movie" to class="movie". 
Change your html like below:

```
enter code here

 <li>
    <p>
       <a class="movie" href="javascript:void(0);"> title </a>
    </p>
    <img alt="Image name" src="thumbnailSrc">
 </li>
```

Now try below code:

```
$(document.body).on('click','.movie',function(){
    console.log('Hello World!');
});
```

**EDIT**

Change void() to void(0) to make it work correctly in your anchor tag.

Comment: This works but it throws `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )"`. Why this works and the others solutions don't?

Comment: It is curious because if I run this

    $(document.body).on('click','.movie',function(){
        
    });

There is still an error but empty. Anyway, thanks _Simple Man

Comment: Please see my edited answer. Sorry for delay. Tell me if it dosen't work. Probably it will. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of repeating `id's`**(Id's must be unique in a page)** repeat `class` and use `document.ready()` block as shown :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.movie').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Hello World!');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems (at least):

- Wrap your JS in a [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function
- Instead of multiple IDs, use a class.

Answer (score 0):

Please try folowing.

```
<li>
    <p>
       <a class="movie" href="#"> title </a>
    </p>
    <img src="thumbnailSrc">
</li>

$('.ClassName').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // You code here with 
    //$(this).text(); or $(this).html();
    console.log('Hello World!');
});
```

Hope this will help you.